# android studio Jsoup missing content

Tags: android, kotlin, jsoup, metadata

I am creating a link preview in android studio, I've succeeded but then when I started to further test my work I've noticed that sometimes the link doesn't show all of the required content, for example I tried to open

```
"https://www.google.com"
```

with jsoup like so

```
Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com").get()
```

and the following is the result document that I got

[image]

then I went to https://try.jsoup.org/ to check the results from the same link, this was the result

https://try.jsoup.org/~sY0KUiRifqNt-BzogCFyQuXVeDc

[image]

if you check the header you can see that the "description" is missing as well as other content in the body... does anyone know the reason behind that? I would like to get all of the content.

thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

So I looked around more and I found out that I never was getting the right information from the start.

I went to https://www.google.com and then pressed **CTRL + U** you will see that this is the exact same information that the Jsoup gets... but still using the https://try.jsoup.org/ gets all the metadata information so why doesn't the android version do the same?

Answer (score 1):

Your browser and your android device send different user agent string to the server. Some servers ignore it, some return different responses to differenr user agents. The solution is to add a user agent string to your request -

```
Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com")
.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36")
.get()
```

You can change the string according to your needs.